# How can i make text showing up after some period of time?

Tags: game-development, game-maker, game-maker-language

I am a newbie. i wanted make little text showing under the door after player reaching the door and waiting some time, but text doesn't show up. text part works fine, but " call_later" not.

```
var _callback = function()
{
    draw_set_font(v_lol);
    draw_set_colour(c_yellow);
    draw_text(x, y-30, "press key up");
}
        
if place_meeting(x,y,obj_player) = true 
{ 
    var _handle  = call_later(10,time_source_units_seconds,_callback);
}
```

Comment: Would be nice to specify which language you are using :) Guess that this is JS. In this case try writing your if placement in the right way - if (place_meeting(x, y, obj_player) == true). You could remove == true in JS, leaving: if (place_meeting(x,y,obj_player)) {... }

Comment: @AleksejVasinov One of the Tags is game-maker-language, (that's literally their language name), so I think that's clear enough. :) GML is a lot looser in code conventions, so conditions don't even need to be between brackets

Comment: I was not aware, sorry :) But anyway there should be double equality sign in == true.
https://manual.yoyogames.com/#t=GameMaker_Language%2FGML_Overview%2FLanguage_Features%2FIf_Else_and_Conditional_Operators.htm

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with `call_later`, but it looks like you followed the example in the Gamemaker Documents: https://manual.yoyogames.com/GameMaker_Language/GML_Reference/Time_Sources/call_later.htm

What I assume what happens is that the countdown for `call_later` resets as long as you're in front of the door. (the document don't specify if it's in the Create or Step Event) Maybe you can put a boolean check so it only goes through the if-statement once until it has showed the message. (Maybe there are better alternates, but this is more for confirmation sake)

Example:

```
//For Create Event:
bool beginCountDown = false;

//Step Event:
var _callback = function()
{
    draw_set_font(v_lol);
    draw_set_colour(c_yellow);
    draw_text(x, y-30, "press key up");
    beginCountDown = false;
}
        
if (place_meeting(x,y,obj_player) = true && beginCountDown == false)
{ 
    var _handle  = call_later(10,time_source_units_seconds,_callback);
    beginCountDown = true;
}
```